# Belkin router issue

Tags: router, ping

My cousin and I bought a wireless Belkin router for testing purposes. Please keep in mind for all of our tests there is no ethernet cable plugged in, just the router's power cord.

We have been trying to "flood" it with PING requests on its default address `192.168.2.1`, but it isn't doing a thing; not even logging any attempts of too many requests. I've disabled the firewall, disabled PING request block, etc. Any idea why this thing isn't being affected? We sent 4 million packets and it hasn't done a thing. Quite odd!

Thanks.

Comment: (8000 each time btw)

Comment: By hasn't done a thing, do you mean that it doesn't respond to the ping requests, or hasn't changed it's behavior in response to the flood? Also, you can edit your question instead of leaving comments on it.

Comment: It responds fine but our PINGs have not affected the router in any way.

Comment: Hmmm what about opening some ports?

Comment: What are you expecting to see that you aren't seeing?  Seems normal to me.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Sounds sketchy and I hope you don't get a real answer. Sounds like you are trying to learn how to maliciously take down a friend's, enemy's, or neighbor's router. That is wrong (not to mention illegal) and I think this question should be removed and you banned.

Answer (score 2):

A ping flood from a single computer isn't going to take down the router.  The router is meant to handle traffic from multiple computers and has a very optimized firmware.

Maybe if you got 20 computers to all send pings at the same time you would be able to slow down the router, or create a DDOS.

Comment: We've sent 4 million from two computers. I'm pretty sure it should be affected after that.

Comment: @walr1 Based on what? Responding to a ping is not computationally expensive. You might see a *slight* increase in response time when using two computers, since they can produce more requests than the router can responses, which will become more noticeable the more computers you use. This is also assuming that the computers can send packets at the same speed as the router - if the router can send packets faster than the computers can, you won't notice any delays.

Answer (score 0):

Check your settings.  Don't be surprised by anything SOHO routers do when it comes to ICMP.  I have a D-Link 4500 that responds to pings sent to it, but doesn't respond on TTL going to 0, as in tracert.

Comment: I've checked the settings over and over again. Basically disabled everything.